# Hola, tengo una duda sobre si tengo mal asignado mi codigo

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Estoy intentando llamar varias imagenes que residen en uno de mis package con el metodo **setIcon**, en realidad busco que el metodo me pueda mostrar las imagen que yo asigne en mis jlabel. Apliqué el metodo que verán a continuación en el codigo pero este de cierta forma me lanza un error. diganme si lo tengo mal

```
     `import javax.swing.Icon;
      import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
      import javax.swing.JLabel;
      import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
      import javax.swing.JPanel;
      import javax.swing.Panel;

       public dashboard() {
       initComponents();
       this.setExtendedState(6);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

       setColor(btnInicio2,Lbl_inicio,"/iconosV2/home-altVr.png");       
       resetColor(btnCliente2,Lbl_clientes,"/iconosV1/users-altV.png");
       resetColor(btnProveedor2,Lbl_proveedor,"/iconosV1/truckV.png");
       resetColor(btnProductos2,Lbl_productos,"/iconosV1/boxV.png");//
       resetColor(btnFacturacion2,Lbl_facturacion,"/iconosV1/receipt-altV.png");
       resetColor(btnRegistro2,Lbl_registro,"/iconosV1/billV.png");

       //METODO QUE USO
       private void setColor(JPanel pane, JLabel lbl, String url) 
   {
       pane.setBackground(new Color(89, 106, 158));
       lbl.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
       lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(url)));
  
    //entiendo que donde va (url) debe ir la ruta de mi imagen pero este 
    //solo llamaria a una sola y yo quiero es hacer un llamado de varias
    
   }

   private void resetColor(JPanel pane, JLabel lbl, String url) {
           pane.setBackground(new Color(57,76,135)); 
           lbl.setForeground(new Color(166, 166, 166));
           lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(url)));
   }`
```

Answer (score 0):

despues de las importaciones, debe definirse el nombre de una clase, esta clase incluye todo el código que tienes.

```
public class XX {
   //codigo que esta presentando;
}
```

Una sugerencia: empieza a aprender javafx para el manejo de las interfaces gráficas ya que swing es obsoleto.